Query for areas/relations containing private ways in OSM
I would like to find gated communities in Argentina. Thus far, I have been able to filter the ones which are explicitly tagged as such, i.e. those with the tag residential=gated. This is the query I have used:
{{geocodeArea:Argentina}}->.searchArea;
(
  nwr["landuse"="residential"]["residential"="gated"](area.searchArea);
  nwr["landuse"="residential"]["barrier"="fence"](area.searchArea);
  nwr["gated_community"="yes"](area.searchArea);
);

However, there are several places which are not tagged in this way, but I know that are gated communities, like this place.
In this particular case, and in many others, I see there are ways inside tagged as access=private (e.g. this way).
Hence, my question is how can I search for areas which contain ways tagged like this?

For this can be used is_in. This outputs all elements that have the provided points respectively nodes inside. Ways are not supported with is_in, so the nodes of the ways must be extracted before using the > query statement. Furthermore, the resulting areas are to be processed using pivot.
This outputs all areas with paths that are private:
{{geocodeArea:Argentina}} -> .searchArea;
way["access"="private"](area.searchArea); >; 
is_in;
wr(pivot)["landuse"="residential"];
out geom;

@ Overpass
The amount of extracted areas can be further reduced, since the paths are already defined with gated and fence and are not needed again in the result:
{{geocodeArea:Argentina}} -> .searchArea;
way["access"="private"](area.searchArea); >; 
is_in;
wr(pivot)["landuse"="residential"]["residential"!="gated"]["barrier"!="fence"];
out geom;

@ Overpass

Thank you! This looks quite promising!
